# Multiple @DataModelSelection setters

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, seam2

I am working on a project that uses seam 2.3.1 and tomcat7 and everything is just fine when I build and deploy it under jdk1.6. And now I'd like to migrate the project to java 8, so I changed maven build configuration to use jdk1.8.0_51 as alternate JRE and built project again. But on startup I face the following exception:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance 
    of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create Component: actionTypeListBB
at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1271)
at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.installComponents(Initialization.java:1187)
at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:806)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple @DataModelSelection setters for: actionTypeList
at org.jboss.seam.Component.initMembers(Component.java:584)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:244)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:205)
at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1255)
```

I am not expert on this technologies and definitely missing something. Can you please help me with this?